# extend mouse events

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am developing a multitarget app and the scenario is that i have to use some conditional compilation to get mouse and/or touch events.

So I am doing something like this:

Extending:

```
package  {

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;



    public class fackeClick extends MouseEvent {


        public static const CLICKS:String = "click";

        public function fackeClick(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = true, cancelable:Boolean = false, localX:Number=0, localY:Number=0, relatedObject:InteractiveObject = null, ctrlKey:Boolean = false, altKey:Boolean = false, shiftKey:Boolean = false, buttonDown:Boolean = false, delta:int = 0)
        {

          super(eventType, bubbles, cancelable, localX, localY, relatedObject, ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, buttonDown, delta);
         }


    }

}
```

And using like this:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import fackeClick;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {


        public function Main() {
            stage.addEventListener(fackeClick.CLICKS, tryClick);
        }
        //
        private function tryClick(e:fackeClick):void {

                    trace(e);

            }
    }

}
```

This usage throws me an runtime error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::MouseEvent@31510089 to fackeClick.

If I switch private function tryClick(e:fackeClick)  to private function tryClick(e:MouseEvent) it works. But I really need to pass the custom event to the function.

"fackeClick" will be a class written in different packages, extending Mouse or TouchEvents

Please, I know that we can use clickevents as touchevents etc.
I am in very peculiar scenario and a really have to do like this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that is thrown is because your `fackeClick.CLICKS` uses the same String as the `MouseEvent.CLICK`. So now Flash catches the `'click'` and dispatches the normal `MouseEvent`. Which conflicts with your `fakeClick` class.

This brings me to the next issue, I don't think it's possible to extend these events like this. Flash handles the `MouseEvents` itself so simply extending `MouseEvent` won't make Flash dispatch your custom event instead of the real `MouseEvent` (or `TouchEvent`).

More (official) information about how Flash handles the 'click' event, can be found in the documentation:

[InteractiveObject - click](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3aclick)

But then again I'm not 100% about this and maybe you can figure out a workaround by listening to MouseEvents and TouchEvents on the stage and dispatch your own event afterwards. It won't be pretty but maybe it'll work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I have already tried several ways with no success. I was guessing that it is not possible at all like you said.
But it is really annoying. Why the player cannot convert the event since it extends mouseevent?
I just wanna use the same name, dammit! :)

Anyways, thanks a lot for the help.